# bash: variables into sed expressions

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed to replace all lines in the txt file matching the selected patterns in each line

```
#make 2 substitutions with sed
sed 's|\/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Analys/output/CNE/RG/||; s|\.log||'
```

where I need to replace the path "/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Analys/output/CNE/RG/"

However, if I define the path into variable set in bash script

```
path_to_replace='/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Analys/output/CNE/RG/'
```

and then to use it with sed

```
sed 's|\"${path_to_replace}"||; s|\.log||'
```

sed do nothing. How the variable could be properly used with the sed function?

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes you used `sed "s|${path_to_replace}||; s|\.log||"`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: if doesn't work, please **[edit]** your question with what reason it's failing, adding error messages or enough details